# Android Switch Status

Tags: android, switch-statement, status

Good morning, I just started studying Android application development, using Android Studio. My first experiment consisted in creating 3 EditText, 1 AnalogClock and 1 Switch, with "Slide Me!" as text.

With this code:

```
public void Slider(View v) {
    int pri,sec,som;
    EditText txt_pri = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Primo);
    EditText txt_sec = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Secondo);
    EditText txt_som = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Somma);
    AnalogClock Orologio = (AnalogClock)findViewById(R.id.analogClock);
    pri=Integer.parseInt(txt_pri.getText().toString());
    sec=Integer.parseInt(txt_sec.getText().toString());
    som = pri + sec;
    txt_som.setText(""+som);
    Orologio.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

which is the only thing I added, other than deleting the "Hello World!" default textbox, I am able to read two numbers and put their sum in the third EditText, while making the analog clock disappear.

What I would like to do next would be to check the switch status and do

the sum, the disappearing clock and changing "Slide Me!" to something else, if switching on;

erasing the sum EditText, the reappearing of the clock and put "Slide Me!" back, if switching off;

but I have no idea where to start from.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Ciao, Lupo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Switch do you mean toggle? To handle toggle use the following code..

```
public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
// Is the toggle on?
     boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();

     if (on) {
         //set text here
     } else {
        // set anything else here
      }
    }
```

Or do this

```
ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglebutton);
  toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new  CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked) {
        // The toggle is enabled
    } else {
        // The toggle is disabled
    }
}
```

});

Comment: In the widgets, right above the ToggleButton, there is a "Switch", which is the one I am referring to...

Comment: Do as above. Or here is the link on switches. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html

Comment: I am running Android Studio 1.0.2 on Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit. I did everything you suggested (copy/paste) and get this error: 

/home/Utente/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_21_x86 -netspeed full -netdelay none -force-32bit
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc

Comment: add this   android:onClick="onToggleClicked"  to your toggle button or do as edited above.

Comment: onToggleClicked is the method name that you wrote to invoke in your toggle button